# javascript object - why undefined properties?

Tags: javascript

Why does this code produce an undefined for `setMedium` and `setLarge`? I would like these to look like similar methods to `setSmall`. What do I have to do to correctly define these as methods?

```
function Box() {
    this.length = 14;
    this.width = 10;
    this.height = 6;
    this.setSmall = function (){
        this.length = 14;
        this.width = 10;
        this.height = 6;
    }
    this.setMedium = setBoxDimensions(16,14,6);
    this.setLarge = setBoxDimensions(24,14,6);
    this.initBoxDimensions = this.setSmall;

    function setBoxDimensions(length, width, height){
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
var newBox = new Box();
newBox.setSmall();
console.log(newBox);
```

Comment: `this.setMedium = function() { setBoxDimensions.call(this, 16, 14, 16); };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to assign a function to an object. Right now you're invoking a function, not assigning it.

If you want to invoke `setBoxDimensions` with static arguments, then you assign an anonymous function to `this.setMedium/Large` and have that invoke `setBoxDimensions`.

But it also seems that you don't want `setBoxDimensions` to be exposed. In that case, you need to invoke it via the `.call()` method, which lets you set its `this` value.

```
function Box() {

    // use the setBoxDimensions since we have it.
    this.setSmall = function (){
        setBoxDimensions.call(this, 14,10,6);
    }

    this.setSmall(); // to initialize instead of repeating the code above

    // assign anonymous functions that invoke `setBoxDimensions`
    this.setMedium = function() {
        // call setBoxDimensions, and set its `this` to the current `this`
        setBoxDimensions.call(this, 16,14,6); 
    }
    this.setLarge = function() {
        // call setBoxDimensions, and set its `this` to the current `this`
        setBoxDimensions.call(this, 24,14,6);
    }

    this.initBoxDimensions = this.setSmall;

    function setBoxDimensions(length, width, height){
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
var newBox = new Box();
newBox.setSmall();
console.log(newBox);
```

---

If you wanted `setBoxDimensions` to be a publicly exposed method, then you can set it on `this`. Also, it's probably a good idea to take advantage of prototypal inheritance here.:

```
function Box() {
    this.setSmall();
}

Box.prototype.setSmall = function (){
    this.setBoxDimensions(14,10,6);
}
Box.prototype.setMedium = function() {
    this.setBoxDimensions(16,14,6); 
}
Box.prototype.setLarge = function() {
    this.setBoxDimensions(24,14,6);
}

Box.prototype.initBoxDimensions = Box.prototype.setSmall;

Box.prototype.setBoxDimensions = function(length, width, height){
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

var newBox = new Box();
newBox.setSmall();
console.log(newBox);
```

Comment: Awesome! this totally works. I always read about `apply` and `call` and then always forgot because I never used this technique. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your initialization statements like this:

```
this.setMedium = setBoxDimensions(16,14,6);
```

are **calling** the function "setBoxDimensions". If you want "setMedium" to be a call to "setBoxDimensions" with particular arguments, you need to make it be a function to do that:

```
this.setMedium = function() {
    this.setBoxDimensions(16,14,6);
}.bind(this);
```

Whenever you mention a function and follow that by a parenthesized list of arguments, you're making a function call then and there.

The `.bind()` function used above arranges for `this` to be correctly set in the anonymous wrapper function. An alternative that will work in really old browsers is:

```
var that = this;
this.setMedium = function() {
    that.setBoxDimensions(16, 14, 6);
};
```

Comment: When I did this, I was able to set the functions but when I call the method `setMedium`, the length/width/heights are not set correctly. I got the following object back after calling `setMedium`: Box {length: 14, width: 10, height: 6, setSmall: function, setMedium: function…}

Comment: his `setBoxDimensions` isn't a property on the object, so this won't work. Also, `.bind()` won't be needed. He can just set it as a property and then call it from the `this` value within `.setMedium` function that you created.

Comment: @squint: not sure what you mean, can you clarify? I got an error with pointy's code

Answer (score 1):

because setBoxDimensions does not return a value. Also the context of setBoxDimension is the global object.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are trying to achieve is called partial function application, which is basically creating a derived function from an exisiting one, but that will be called with predefined parameters.

```
this.setMedium = setBoxDimensions.bind(this, 16,14,6);
this.setLarge = setBoxDimensions.bind(this, 24,14,6);
```

Comment: @squint Indeed, lol... not sure what I was thinking ;) It's probably because I am so used to call private functions using `call` that it got in the way =P